# Send error from controller to vue.js and remove square brackets

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I can send the error with this code, but when the error is shown in the vue.js I cant remove the square brackets

In controller

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages(['Esta pregunta esta en una encuesta, por lo tanto no lo puede eliminar.']);
```

Output in vue

```
['Esta pregunta esta en una encuesta, por lo tanto no lo puede eliminar.']
```

This is how I'm displaying it in the vue.js, the `$page.auth.user.errors[0]` comes from using inertia-vue, it just gets the message thrown form the controller

```
this.$message({
    type: 'error',
    message: this.$page.auth.user.errors[0]
});
```

I've tried doing this

```
this.$message({
    type: 'error',
    message: this.$page.auth.user.errors[0].replace('["', "").replace('"]', "")
});
```

But this doesn't work, this is the full remove question method this is in, in the `<script>`

```
remove(row) {
    this.$confirm('Desea borrar esta pregunta?', 'Advertencia', {
        confirmButtonText: 'Si',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        cancelButtonClass: 'el-button--info',
        confirmButtonClass: 'el-button--warning',
        type: 'warning'
    }).then(() => {
        this.loading = true;
        this.$inertia.delete(this.baseUrl + '/' + row.id)
            .then(
                () => {
                    if (!this.$page.auth.user.errors[0]) {
                        this.$message({
                            type: 'success',
                            message: 'Eliminado correctamente.'
                        });
                    } else {
                        this.$message({
                            type: 'error',
                            message: this.$page.auth.user.errors[0]
                        });
                    }
                    this.reset();
                    this.loading = false;
                },
                (res) => {
                    this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            )
    })
},
```

Comment: What do you mean with "this doesn't work" when trying to replace the brackets? I am assuming that you cannot replace, because it is not actually a string but still an array.  Can you try doing `message: this.$page.auth.user.errors[0][0]`?

Comment: As a tip: go to the place where you do `this.$message(...)` and instead do `console.log(this.$page.auth.user)` and then check in the console how your errors are structured

Comment: @MatthiasS if I do `this.$page.auth.user.errors[0][0]` it shows the success message instead of the error. and the console log show these four folders `app`, `auth`, `flash`, and `errors` inside the errors folder there is an item that looks like this `0: ["Esta pregunta esta en una encuesta, por lo tanto no lo puede eliminar.", __ob__: Observer]`

Comment: I think you did `this.$page.auth.user.errors[0][0]` at the wrong place. You need to do it in your `else` part, so `else {
                        this.$message({
                            type: 'error',
                            message: this.$page.auth.user.errors[0][0]
                        });
                    }`

Comment: Can you open this and check in the console which example is more like yours? https://codepen.io/matzeso/pen/wvaozoR

Comment: I don't use inertia, but I thik you have to add a catch... something like `this.$inertia.delete(this.baseUrl + '/' + row.id).then(() => {
    // ...
.catch(error => {
    if (error.response.status === 422) {
        for (const val of Object.values(data)) {
            for (const message of Object.values(val)) {
                console.log(message);
            }
        }
    }
})`

Comment: @MatthiasS I just went the easy route and instead of calling `message: this.$page.auth.user.errors[0]` I just did `message: 'typed my message in here'`